# The dataset refers to a shared dataset which is not available

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ssrs-2008-r2

I am accessing a SSRS Report in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application through Reporting Services web service (SOAP API).

but getting below error when try to send comma seperated parameter.

```
"The dataset refers to a shared dataset which is not available."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above error was occurring due to a string containing comma separated values that i was trying to send for a  parameter to render a SSRS report programmatically using SOAP API interface.

If anyone want to know how to send comma separated values for a SSRS Report parameter, please refer [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlforum/archive/2010/12/21/faq-how-do-i-pass-a-multi-value-parameter-into-a-report-with-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-web-services-api.aspx) link.

Answer (score 0):

While not *directly* related to the question, this was the only SO question that came up in my searching so I wanted to toss out another possible reason for the message `The dataset 'X' refers to a shared data set 'Y', which is not available` that I ran into:

I was trying to set a parameter to a value not within the list (e.g. I had a list of date ranges that was restricted based on other parameters, but was trying to set the param to a range value outside that list).  So, my solution is adding a check before the API call to make sure that the desired range will actually be listed (at the moment using some separate logic to figure this out, not any SSRS interaction).

Because I was running the report multiple times for different sets of parameters this took me a while to figure out. The error also referred to a shared dataset that was only used to set the default value of this list, not the shared dataset that populated this list, which made it all the more confusing.