# What does the error "The dataset refers to a shared dataset which is not available." mean?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report template (.rdl file) that has an embedded dataset 'X' that refers to a shared dataset 'Y' (.rsd file). Both files are located in the same folder.

When I try to generate a report, I get the error "The dataset 'X' refers to a shared dataset 'Y' which is not available."

The datasets do not contain [comma-separated strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28501085/11599796) or [empty values](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5212ed7b-6cc7-4038-93ae-fef2c644601b/does-reportexecutionservice-ssrs-2012-support-shared-datasets?forum=sqlreportingservices).

UPDATE (2019-06-07): contrary to the above, the data did contain empty values. I didn't realize a filter was emptying the final result.

I've made sure that the data source is shared, as well.

Other shared datasets are recognized, but this one isn't.

I've looked at database permissions, but I've been able to run the SQL queries from the datasets in SSMS without problems, which seems to indicate that the permissions are valid. Perhaps the application using the datasets needs specific database permissions..?

This is the problematic dataset:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <SharedDataSet xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/shareddatasetdefinition">
      <DataSet Name="">
        <Query>
          <DataSourceReference>XXX</DataSourceReference>
          <DataSetParameters>
            <DataSetParameter Name="@Foo">
              <ReadOnly>false</ReadOnly>
              <Nullable>false</Nullable>
              <OmitFromQuery>false</OmitFromQuery>
              <rd:DbType>Object</rd:DbType>
            </DataSetParameter>
          </DataSetParameters>
          <CommandText>***a SQL query***</Query>
        <Fields>***some fields***
        </Fields>
        <Filters>***some filters***
        </Filters>
      </DataSet>
    </SharedDataSet>
```

This one seems to pose no problems:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <SharedDataSet xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/shareddatasetdefinition">
      <DataSet Name="">
        <Query>
          <DataSourceReference>XXX</DataSourceReference>
          <DataSetParameters>
            <DataSetParameter Name="@FooId">
              <ReadOnly>false</ReadOnly>
              <Nullable>false</Nullable>
              <OmitFromQuery>false</OmitFromQuery>
              <rd:DbType>Object</rd:DbType>
            </DataSetParameter>
            <DataSetParameter Name="@BarId">
              <ReadOnly>false</ReadOnly>
              <Nullable>false</Nullable>
              <OmitFromQuery>false</OmitFromQuery>
              <rd:DbType>Object</rd:DbType>
            </DataSetParameter>
          </DataSetParameters>
          <CommandText>***SQL QUERY***</CommandText>
        </Query>
        <Fields>***some fields***
        </Fields>
        <Filters>
          <Filter>***some filters***
          </Filter>
        </Filters>
      </DataSet>
    </SharedDataSet>
```

UPDATE (2019-06-06): Apparently, removing the filters and ensuring that the query does not yield an empty result fixes the error. If there are filter(s) or if the query yields an empty result, the error returns. I have no clue yet why this is so.

UPDATE (2019-06-07): The filter caused the dataset to return an empty set of records (0 rows). This is what seems to cause the error. In all tests I did, cases where there's at least one row of data worked and cases where there's 0 rows showed the error.

Comment: Is this error generating in a local report builder environment? On the report server manager? both?

Comment: Do you have access to the folder that the shared dataset is located in as well as the data source that the shared dataset uses? These permissions are set in the report server regardless of your permission level in the SQL Server.

Comment: Steve-o169: we have a separate server for the reports solution. The folder in which the datasets are located in on this server. We access the server from a different one via the browser in the local environment.

So I think the answer to your question is in a local report builder environment. 

StevenWhite: I'll look into it, thanks for the tip. Though other shared datasets (located in the same folder) do not cause the same error, so if this works, the next question would be why some datasets are available and some not.